# Replace characters in cells that contain a specific substring

Tags: python, pandas, replace, contains, mask

I have the following setup:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": ["Amount 3,7$", "Amount 6,7$", "Amount 1,3$"],
    "b": ["2,3", " Amount 3,5", "4,7"]
})
```

I want to find any cells with the substring `Amount` and replace the character `,` with `.`

I expect:

```
    a           b
0   Amount 3.7$     2,3
1   Amount 6.7$     Amount 3.5
2   Amount 1.3$     4,7
```

I have tried:

```
for column in data.columns:
    data[column] = data[column][data[column].str.contains("Amount", na=False)].replace(",", ".", regex=True)
```

What I get is:

```
    a           b
0   Amount 3.7$     NaN
1   Amount 6.7$     NaN
2   Amount 1.3$     NaN
```

Somehow the mask is not working as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `applymap`

```
data.applymap(lambda s: s.replace(',', '.') if 'Amount' in s else s)
```

---

```
             a            b
0  Amount 3.7$          2,3
1  Amount 6.7$   Amount 3.5
2  Amount 1.3$          4,7
```

Comment: Wow that's so simple stupid and it works, Thanks. I've tried similar things but this actually solved it.

Comment: Actually it's better to use `if 'Amount' in str(s)`, else this can cause an error for other `dtype`s

Answer (score 1):

One approach:

```
data["b"] = np.where(data["b"].str.contains("Amount"), data["b"].str.replace(",", "."), data["b"])
print(data)
```

**Output**

```
             a            b
0  Amount 3,7$          2,3
1  Amount 6,7$   Amount 3.5
2  Amount 1,3$          4,7
```

An alternative is to use the following list comprehension:

```
data["b"] = [x.replace(",", ".") if "Amount" in x else x for x in data["b"]]
```

If `"Amount"` is always at the beginning, you could use a more elaborated regex, as below:

```
data["b"] = data["b"].str.replace("(.*Amount.*)(,)", r"\1.", regex=True)
```